# Weak convergence of measure and point wise convergence of density

Tags: measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $T>0$, let $X=[0,T]$, $f_n, f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\mu_n, \mu \in \mathcal{M}(X)$ s.t. 
$$ f_n \mu_n \rightharpoonup f\mu $$
where $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is the space of positive finite Borel measures on $X$.

Suppose I know that, for every $t \in [0,T]$ I can extract a converging subsequence $f_{n_k}(t)$ converging to $g(t) \in \mathbb{R}$. Clearly the subsequence depends on the point.

Under which condition I am allowed to say that 
$$f(t)=g(t)$$
for $\mu$-a.e. $t \in X$?

Comment: It seems hard to hope for anything when your measures keep changing. Assume that $\nu_n\to \nu$ weakly and pick $f_{n}$ to be *any* convergent sequence of positive functions with limit $g$ (in whatever topology on the space of functions). Let $f$ be any function not equal to $g$ a.e. Then, define $\mu_n= f_n^{-1} \nu_n$ and $\mu=f^{-1} \nu$. Then, we are in the above set up, but $f$ and $g$ were chosen to be incompatible. I think there's not much hope for your statement unless $\mu_n$ and $\mu$ have density with respect to some common measure and then applying Scheffe.

Comment: Suppose $\mu_n$ is the average of $n$ equally-spaced point masses on $[0,1]$ and all $f_n=\mathbb 1_{\mathbb Q}$.  Then $f_n\mu_n$ converges weakly to $f\mu$ where $f$ is the constant $1$ and $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure.  Your $g$ is $\mathbb 1_{\mathbb Q}$ which is not equal to $f$ almost everywhere.